# Create Tab panel as submit event

Tags: laravel, tabs

```
<div class="panel panel-primary tabs-style-2">
    <div class="tab-menu-heading">
        <div class="tabs-menu1">
            <!-- Tabs -->
            <ul class="nav panel-tabs main-nav-line" >
                <li><a href="{{ route('admin.productionData.index') }}" class="nav-link {{ $no_production_tab ? '' : 'active' }}" data-toggle="tab" >Production</a></li>
                <li><a href="?no_production_tab=1" class="nav-link {{ $no_production_tab ? 'active' : '' }}" data-toggle="tab" >No Production</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my code, its working fine but rather then get method i want use with post method for **No Production** tab

temp i had added method with href but want to work as post method so url will not display in address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="?no_production_tab=1" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('form-to-submit').submit();">
    No production
</a>

<form id="form-to-submit" action="?no_production_tab=1" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

You can use the link like this.